# How to keep the version in the file name of a library included in a eclipse-plugin with Tycho

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, tycho

I've got an plugin which I'm building with Tycho 0.12.0. This plugin has a (snapshot) maven dependency such as `foobar:0.1.1-SNAPSHOT`. This dependency is regularly updated (each day). The physical file contains the date and time of the snapshot (foobar-0.1.0-20120507.135021-6.jar).  I want to build with a snapshot because I want to test with the latest dev version.

So, when I build the project, the updated dependency gets copied into the `lib/` directory as expected, and the compile and build goes fine.

However, the MANIFEST.MF Bundle-ClassPath doesn't get updated, so when the plugin is installed, it doesn't actually work, because the classpath is incorrect.

The solution that I'm currently using is to override the name of the file being written by the maven-dependency-plugin to be `foobar-0.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`, but I would prefer to keep the full version number of the snapshot so that I can refer to it. Is this possible? Is it possible to update the MANIFEST.MF with the fully qualified name of the SNAPSHOT dependency being used, or would I have to manually manipulate the MANIFEST.MF myself?

I can write something to manipulate the MANIFEST.MF myself, but I was wondering if there was a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather strip the version during copy:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-mojo.html#stripVersion

then you have a stable jar file name.

Comment: That is what I'm currently doing. But I would like to keep the dated filename.